# ubuntu installed on partition; would like to reinstall on same partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lvm

I'm looking to reinstall Ubuntu. I installed it originally with partitions to keep the '/home' directory separate from root '/'. How do I reinstall without overwriting my 'home' directory?

- I have a copy of the `/etc/fstab` file
- I have a bootable usb drive with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on it.

I'm looking to re-install ubuntu on the root '/' partition with the 18.04 Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use my home directory on a separate partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283060/how-do-i-use-my-home-directory-on-a-separate-partition)

Comment: I think, for lvm the next info would be useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/930959/can-i-manually-set-up-lvm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I link pre-existing /home partition to account when reinstalling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926841/how-do-i-link-pre-existing-home-partition-to-account-when-reinstalling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the bootable USB to install Ubuntu. When given the options similar to the screenshot, I selected "something else". the following screen showed me how my drive was currently partitioned. I selected each partitions location and finished installing Ubuntu. Ubuntu installed itself over the root '/' partition.

Installation was successful.

[image: screenshot of installation step with several methods for installing ubuntu]